# Rewrite equation to solve for $x$, not $y$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I am doing calculus integration, and need to show my work for Horizontal slicing (even though Vertical slicing is far easier).

The equation is $$y= x/\sqrt{2x^2+1}$$

I need to rewrite the equation so that it is $x=\;...$ in order to horizontally slice it (in other words, it should be rewritten so that it is dependent on $y$). 
This isn't exactly a calculus question, although it is being used for calculus. I'm probably missing something that is pretty obvious. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Heres a tip:  Take reciprocals.
Notice $$\left( \frac{1}{y}\right)^2=\left( \frac{\sqrt{2x^2+1}}{x}\right)^2=\frac{2x^2+1}{x^2}=2+\frac{1}{x^2}$$

Then we get $$\frac{1}{x^2}=\frac{1}{y^2}-2$$

Take reciprocals again and we find
$$x^2=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{y^2}-2}$$

Take square roots, and we are finished.

Hope that helps

Edit:  Just to make things complete I decided to add the final line: $$x=\pm \sqrt{\frac{y^2}{1-2y^2}}$$

Comment: Thanks for the help! I can't believe that I missed this solution with the reciprocal.

Comment: @Isaac: You are correct! Should be fixed.

Comment: Yes, you got it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on an interval where $x\ge 0$, $$\begin{align}
\frac{x}{\sqrt{2x^2+1}}&=\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{2x^2+1}}
\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{2x^2+1-1}{2(2x^2+1)}}
\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{2x^2+1}\right)}
\end{align}$$
Now that there's only one instance of $x$ on the right side, you should be able to more easily solve for $x$.